# Excel VBA variable = MATCH Array formula

Tags: excel, vba, array-formulas

I want to return the row number where column A has val1 and column B has val2.

Currently, for testing purposes, I have an array formula in a cell, and it works fine.

A2 ={MATCH(1,(Data!A:A="val1")*(Data!B:B="val2"),0)}

I now want to use that formula in VBA with the result (the row number) being in a variable.

val1 and val2 are 2 string variables I would pass to the formula.

I cant seem to find how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Application.evaluate does the job:

```
Public Sub arrfunc()
    val1 = 21
    val2 = 12
    a = Application.Evaluate("MATCH(1,(A:A=" & val1 & ")*(B:B=" & val2 & "),0)")
End Sub
```